# How to make a less than comparison in template meta-programming?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I had this question asked of me on Monday and for the life of me I don't know how to answer.  Since I don't know, I now want to very much find out.  Curiosity is killing this cat.  Given two integers, return the lesser at compile time.

```
template<int M, int N>
struct SmallerOfMandN{
    //and magic happenes here
};
```

Got pointers or how to do it?  (Will start reading [Boost MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) tonight.)

Comment: Get yourself a copy of *"C++ Templates - The Complete Guide"* and maybe *"Modern C++ design"* to really get started on the subject :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is called the minimum of two numbers, and you don't need world heavy weight library like `mpl` to do such a thing:

```
template <int M, int N>
struct compile_time_min
{
    static const int smaller =  M < N ? M : N;
};

int main()
{
    const int smaller = compile_time_min<10, 5>::smaller;
}
```

Of course if it was C++0x you could easily say:

```
constexpr int compile_time_min(int M, int N)
{
    return M < N ? M : N;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int smaller = compile_time_min(10, 5);
}
```

Comment: That's it?  A simple ternary operator?  I had no idea it could work in compile time like that.  Thanks much!  I have to wait another 6 min. to accept this answer.